# Can you post data from PHP

Tags: php

I need to cause a user's browser to post data using PHP to another site.

**Example:** You go to start.com/auto-login-hack (via GET)... then PHP sets the right headers etc. and causes the browser to, via POST, go to 3rdparty.com/login.php with login credentials.

I have done this is the past by having an HTML form and an `onload` script that submits the form to the destination.

I don't know enough about headers and etc. Is this possible? Can anyone link an example? My search skills just turned up how to use `$_POST`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot redirect to a POST; this is a limitation of HTTP. You'd have to use JavaScript to cause the browser to post a form.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can submit POST requests from PHP.

One of your choices is to use [curl](https://www.php.net/curl) as shown in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871431/raw-post-using-curl-in-php).

However, you cannot do redirects.