# Web automation using PHP/cURL

Tags: php, curl, scripting

I want to access to the several pages of this [list](http://www.turismovenezia.it/Dove-Alloggiare/1322597142.html). My try is the code below with which I'm getting an xml file with the data of the hotels of the first page, but I want to access to the pages where the rest of the hotels are..how to do that?

As you can imagine the url for all the pages is the same.

```
<?php

//extract data from the post
extract($_POST);

//set POST variables
$url = 'http://www.turismovenezia.it/index.php';

$fields1 = array(
            'ajax'=>'searchEngineTopdata',
            'next_pair'=>'Dove Allogiare|*',
            'lang'=>'it');


$fields2 = array(

'ajax'=>'xmlSearchEngineResponder',
'xml' => "%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%3F%3E%3CSearchRequest%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.liberologico.com%2Fdbsite%2Fjolly-search%22%20xmlns%3Axsi%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema-instance%22%3E%3CSearch%3E%3CScope%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B%2A%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FScope%3E%3CFilters%3E%3CFilters%20xsi%3Atype%3D%22FilterSpecType%22%3E%3CField%3Eaptve_territorio%3C%2FField%3E%3CValue%3E%3CSingleValue%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B%2A%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FSingleValue%3E%3C%2FValue%3E%3CMode%3ETHESAURUS%3C%2FMode%3E%3COperation%3ELIKE%3C%2FOperation%3E%3C%2FFilters%3E%3CFilters%20xsi%3Atype%3D%22FilterSpecType%22%3E%3CField%3Efull_text_search%3C%2FField%3E%3CValue%3E%3CSingleValue%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B%2A%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FSingleValue%3E%3C%2FValue%3E%3CMode%3EFREE_TEXT%3C%2FMode%3E%3COperation%3ELIKE%3C%2FOperation%3E%3C%2FFilters%3E%3CFilters%20xsi%3Atype%3D%22FilterSpecType%22%3E%3CField%3Elang%3C%2FField%3E%3CValue%3E%3CSingleValue%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5Bit%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FSingleValue%3E%3C%2FValue%3E%3CMode%3EFREE_TEXT%3C%2FMode%3E%3COperation%3EEQUAL%3C%2FOperation%3E%3C%2FFilters%3E%3C%2FFilters%3E%3CSubSearches%3E%3CSearch%3E%3CScope%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5BEventi%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FScope%3E%3C%2FSearch%3E%3CSearch%3E%3CScope%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5BArte%20%26%20Cultura%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FScope%3E%3C%2FSearch%3E%3CSearch%3E%3CScope%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5BMare%20%26%20Natura%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FScope%3E%3C%2FSearch%3E%3CSearch%3E%3CScope%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5BPiatti%20%26%20Prodotti%20tipici%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FScope%3E%3C%2FSearch%3E%3CSearch%3E%3CScope%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5BRelax%20%26%20Divertimento%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FScope%3E%3C%2FSearch%3E%3CSearch%3E%3CScope%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5BDove%20Alloggiare%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FScope%3E%3C%2FSearch%3E%3CSearch%3E%3CScope%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5BDove%20Mangiare%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FScope%3E%3C%2FSearch%3E%3CSearch%3E%3CScope%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5BInformazioni%20Utili%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FScope%3E%3C%2FSearch%3E%3C%2FSubSearches%3E%3C%2FSearch%3E%3CActiveResultSet%3E%3CTab%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5BDove%20Alloggiare%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FTab%3E%3CFirstItem%3E0%3C%2FFirstItem%3E%3CPagerSize%3E10%3C%2FPagerSize%3E%3C%2FActiveResultSet%3E%3C%2FSearchRequest%3E",
'force' => 'false');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields2);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo $result;

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Javi

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative to PHP/cURL scripts: web automation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344136/alternative-to-php-curl-scripts-web-automation)

Comment: Please do not duplicate your own questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all why are you configuring curl twice?

```
//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields2);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
```

Then when you do the first call to first page with $fields2 (The long XML string), the call should return an XML (like you say) and in this XML response there is a field ItemCount which contain the total number of hotels.

And if you look at the long string of XML you send with $fields2 there is a field call 'FirstItem' where contain 0 for the first call. This field is you offset, you can increment it to skip hotels.

Example:

```
$fields2 = array(

'ajax'=>'xmlSearchEngineResponder',
'xml' => "%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%3F%3E%3CSearchRequest%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.liberologico.com%2Fdbsite%2Fjolly-search%22%20xmlns%3Axsi%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema-instance%22%3E%3CSearch%3E%3CScope%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B%2A%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FScope%3E%3CFilters%3E%3CFilters%20xsi%3Atype%3D%22FilterSpecType%22%3E%3CField%3Eaptve_territorio%3C%2FField%3E%3CValue%3E%3CSingleValue%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B%2A%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FSingleValue%3E%3C%2FValue%3E%3CMode%3ETHESAURUS%3C%2FMode%3E%3COperation%3ELIKE%3C%2FOperation%3E%3C%2FFilters%3E%3CFilters%20xsi%3Atype%3D%22FilterSpecType%22%3E%3CField%3Efull_text_search%3C%2FField%3E%3CValue%3E%3CSingleValue%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B%2A%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FSingleValue%3E%3C%2FValue%3E%3CMode%3EFREE_TEXT%3C%2FMode%3E%3COperation%3ELIKE%3C%2FOperation%3E%3C%2FFilters%3E%3CFilters%20xsi%3Atype%3D%22FilterSpecType%22%3E%3CField%3Elang%3C%2FField%3E%3CValue%3E%3CSingleValue%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5Bit%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FSingleValue%3E%3C%2FValue%3E%3CMode%3EFREE_TEXT%3C%2FMode%3E%3COperation%3EEQUAL%3C%2FOperation%3E%3C%2FFilters%3E%3C%2FFilters%3E%3CSubSearches%3E%3CSearch%3E%3CScope%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5BEventi%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FScope%3E%3C%2FSearch%3E%3CSearch%3E%3CScope%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5BArte%20%26%20Cultura%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FScope%3E%3C%2FSearch%3E%3CSearch%3E%3CScope%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5BMare%20%26%20Natura%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FScope%3E%3C%2FSearch%3E%3CSearch%3E%3CScope%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5BPiatti%20%26%20Prodotti%20tipici%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FScope%3E%3C%2FSearch%3E%3CSearch%3E%3CScope%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5BRelax%20%26%20Divertimento%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FScope%3E%3C%2FSearch%3E%3CSearch%3E%3CScope%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5BDove%20Alloggiare%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FScope%3E%3C%2FSearch%3E%3CSearch%3E%3CScope%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5BDove%20Mangiare%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FScope%3E%3C%2FSearch%3E%3CSearch%3E%3CScope%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5BInformazioni%20Utili%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FScope%3E%3C%2FSearch%3E%3C%2FSubSearches%3E%3C%2FSearch%3E%3CActiveResultSet%3E%3CTab%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5BDove%20Alloggiare%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FTab%3E%3CFirstItem%3E0%3C%2FFirstItem%3E%3CPagerSize%3E10%3C%2FPagerSize%3E%3C%2FActiveResultSet%3E%3C%2FSearchRequest%3E",
'force' => 'false');
```

Return you the first 10 Results;

```
$fields2 = array(
'ajax'=>'xmlSearchEngineResponder',
'xml' => "%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%3F%3E%3CSearchRequest%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.liberologico.com%2Fdbsite%2Fjolly-search%22%20xmlns%3Axsi%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema-instance%22%3E%3CSearch%3E%3CScope%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B%2A%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FScope%3E%3CFilters%3E%3CFilters%20xsi%3Atype%3D%22FilterSpecType%22%3E%3CField%3Eaptve_territorio%3C%2FField%3E%3CValue%3E%3CSingleValue%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B%2A%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FSingleValue%3E%3C%2FValue%3E%3CMode%3ETHESAURUS%3C%2FMode%3E%3COperation%3ELIKE%3C%2FOperation%3E%3C%2FFilters%3E%3CFilters%20xsi%3Atype%3D%22FilterSpecType%22%3E%3CField%3Efull_text_search%3C%2FField%3E%3CValue%3E%3CSingleValue%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B%2A%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FSingleValue%3E%3C%2FValue%3E%3CMode%3EFREE_TEXT%3C%2FMode%3E%3COperation%3ELIKE%3C%2FOperation%3E%3C%2FFilters%3E%3CFilters%20xsi%3Atype%3D%22FilterSpecType%22%3E%3CField%3Elang%3C%2FField%3E%3CValue%3E%3CSingleValue%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5Bit%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FSingleValue%3E%3C%2FValue%3E%3CMode%3EFREE_TEXT%3C%2FMode%3E%3COperation%3EEQUAL%3C%2FOperation%3E%3C%2FFilters%3E%3C%2FFilters%3E%3CSubSearches%3E%3CSearch%3E%3CScope%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5BEventi%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FScope%3E%3C%2FSearch%3E%3CSearch%3E%3CScope%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5BArte%20%26%20Cultura%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FScope%3E%3C%2FSearch%3E%3CSearch%3E%3CScope%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5BMare%20%26%20Natura%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FScope%3E%3C%2FSearch%3E%3CSearch%3E%3CScope%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5BPiatti%20%26%20Prodotti%20tipici%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FScope%3E%3C%2FSearch%3E%3CSearch%3E%3CScope%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5BRelax%20%26%20Divertimento%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FScope%3E%3C%2FSearch%3E%3CSearch%3E%3CScope%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5BDove%20Alloggiare%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FScope%3E%3C%2FSearch%3E%3CSearch%3E%3CScope%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5BDove%20Mangiare%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FScope%3E%3C%2FSearch%3E%3CSearch%3E%3CScope%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5BInformazioni%20Utili%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FScope%3E%3C%2FSearch%3E%3C%2FSubSearches%3E%3C%2FSearch%3E%3CActiveResultSet%3E%3CTab%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5BDove%20Alloggiare%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FTab%3E%3CFirstItem%3E10%3C%2FFirstItem%3E%3CPagerSize%3E10%3C%2FPagerSize%3E%3C%2FActiveResultSet%3E%3C%2FSearchRequest%3E",
'force' => 'false');
```

Will return you the next 10 results. Also there is a field call PagerSize thant can allow you to retrieve more result at once.

So i would do the first call to get the total number of hotel, and the loop to get all the other pages.

```
//do first curl call

//then
$totalHotel = 5214; // To retrieve in the first call
$increment = 10; // the number of hotel to treat at once
$nbOfHotelimported = $increment;
while($totalHotel-$increment){
 // do another curl call
 // with FirstItem set to $nbOfHotelimported
 // and pageSizer set to $increment

 $nbOfHotelimported += $increment;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of scraping the initial HTML page itself, you should be fetching the URLs that the site itself accesses using AJAX. You can find out exactly how you should structure your request by using your browser's developer tools to snoop on the AJAX requests made when you request another result page and "copy" them.

By the way, depending on the why and how this might not be the most ethical or legal thing to do.