# Activate URL from within script

Tags: php

I need to be able to "activate"/"fire" a URL from within a PHP file.

Typically the link is clicked on and the underlying script clears some sessions. Due to the system in question, I am unable to clear these sessions myself, so I need to be able to hit that URL from within my PHP script.

Is this possible?

I was thinking maybe cURL or HTTP Request? But even then, I'm not sure how exactly.

Comment: cURL would be the best option

Comment: When you need to activate or fire a link ? any event ? or time based?

Comment: Samy - I'm going to fire it after checking for my own custom session :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends what method do you need:

GET:

```
file_get_contents('http://some.url?params=val');
```

POST:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/871445/1285871