# Unable to find what kind of CURL Post Request

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents, php-stream-wrappers

I've recieved the following data which I need to post to server
[image]

and I cant find out how exactly I need to do it in PHP.
I need to send numbers, but I cant see any parameter thier asking me to send it from.
any ideas how I could send this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you need this:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Details:
http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Or maybe the other way:

[RAW POST using cURL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871431/raw-post-using-curl-in-php)

(I am bit lost in your question.)

The main idea there:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     "numbers\nnumbers\n..." );
```