# Make POST request to custom url using php

Tags: php, http

I need to make http request to custom url using php..
any way to forward raw http header to given url..

---

```html
POST http://myapp.com/register HTTP/1.1
Kraken-Agent: kraken 1.0_101 / Android 4.2.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
User-Agent: Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.2.1; SM-E700H Build/JOP40D)
Host: myapp.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 717

{"android_version":"4.2.1"}
```

---

How to make this request using php.

Comment: Have a look at [GuzzleHttp](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle). It offers all the functionality you need

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RAW POST using cURL in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871431/raw-post-using-curl-in-php)