# CVENT API (Rest api curl)

Tags: php, api, rest, curl

I am trying to get all events from CVENT via REST API. As I understand, at first I need to authorise.

```
    $curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api-platform.cvent.com/ea/oauth2/token",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST =>false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=clietID",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode("clietID:clietSECREAT"),
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    ),
));

// EXECUTE:
$result = curl_exec($curl);
if(!$result){die("Connection Failure");}
curl_close($curl);

var_dump($result);
```

I always get "Request failed authentication/authorization process". clietID and clietID:clietSECREAT are changed and right.

What am I doing wrong in this first step?

The documentation is here: https://developer-portal-eur.cvent.com/documentation#section/Getting-Started/Authentication

Comment: The `grant_type` and `client_id` aren’t headers and should instead be sent as [part of the body](https://stackoverflow.com/a/871445/231316)

Comment: It didn't help me.

Comment: Please post your updated code with those parameters placed in the body and removed from the header.

Comment: Thank you. If you are certain that your credentials are correct, my next recommendation would be to try the manual command line curl version. If it doesn't work there, either, I'd contact the company. Its possible that your credentials aren't approved for the `{hostName}` or something else on their end.

Comment: This looks like an OAuth2 request. The response body and status should shed more light on the issue. Please share

Answer (score 0):

Your `base64_encode()` function needs to actually base 64 encode the client id and client secret.